# How to make a button do an action in Android

Tags: java, android

I am currently in the process of learning Java to create Android apps and have come to a stand still because I am unable to find how to make a floating action button do an action I created. I am using the blank activity option in Android Studio, so the button is already created. How can I change the action?

This is what is in my MainActivity.java. The public boolean openTwitter is my own code. I also modified the .setAction in onCreate to attempt to run openTwitter when the button is pushed.:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction(openTwitter, null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean openTwitter(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = null;
    try {
        // get the Twitter app if possible
        this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=3146095821"));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // no Twitter app, revert to browser
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/itsazul_"));
    }
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is what the floating action button has in the activity_main_screen.xml file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:duplicateParentState="true" />
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it will compile.  setAction takes an int of a string resource to display or a CharSequence of a string.  You can't pass it the name of a method to invoke.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you explain what that means? This is honestly my first time messing with anything Java based besides for some basic Minecraft modding and I'm trying to learn based on what Android Studio provides for me.

Comment: You might want to start with a tutorial that helps you learn Java and Android at the same time if both are new to you.  I wouldn't expect anyone come into this particular task without background on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get it to compile, pass in open twitter(your item name) in the onClick method. However, this is a very basic function that you should be able to find in toturials elsewhere. As a beginner, I recommend you Google a lot of these simple questions and  read over the code to get a feel for it.

Comment: Where would I pass in openTwitter to? I tried Googling what you suggested and couldn't find much that seemed like it would solve my problem, though I may have searched the wrong thing.

Comment: After toying around with what you suggested, I managed to get it working, along with the help of Google's helpful code suggestions. +1 (Turns out my class also had to be private void and I had to pass FloatingActionButton through it as well).